# How to get a listing for properties of many image files?

Tags: windows, imaging, exif, exiftool

I am looking for a tool that can process directories or directory trees containing image files and output a line-by-line plaintext directory listing of file names and image properties.

I am mainly interested in dumping out resolution and color information for TIFF files. Console applications would be preferable. Support for other image formats would be a plus, I guess. I would also like to be able to specify which properties (resolution, DPI, color depth, compression, etc.) would go into the listing.

I thought Lib Tiff would be capable of something as trivial as this, but have not been able to figure out (if) how.

Is there such a batch processing tool on Windows that can dump image information into a text file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[exiftool](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) can do what you want. It's available for Windows, Mac and Linux.

```
exiftool filename
```

will display all the image properties for the specified image file.  Nearly every image file format is supported, including common ones such as JPG and TIFF, and various camera raw formats.

```
exiftool -ApertureValue -ExposureTime *.jpg
```

will display Aperture and Exposure properties for all JPG files in the current directory.